# Python autoformat string containing strings of fixed length

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's say I have an arbitrary number of strings of the same length, e.g.:

```
'01'
'02'
'03'
```

And I need to format them into "one line grid" (separated with spaces) with fixed length. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
>>'{some expression, 15, left}'.format(['01','02','03'])
'01 02 03       '

>>'{some expression, 15, right}'.format(['01','02','03'])
'       01 02 03'
```

Is it possible to do it like this just with [format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#format) or in some other elegant way?

I want to use Python 3.

Comment: How are the arbitrary strings read, from a file or you already have a reference/variable?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye They're meant to be read from a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an apt solution to your problem that uses the inbuilt function [format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
list = ['01','02','03']
list1=' '.join(list)
list_right='{:>15}'.format(list1)   #right 
list_left='{:<15}'.format(list1)    #left
print (list_right)
```

Here, `<` forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects) while, `>`  forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).

Comment: Thank you! Could you just correct the last `print` (I've specified python3, where `print` needs braces ), comments to Python format (to make it possible just to copy and launch the code) and separate the values just with space instead of a dash? I understand the code, but I think these changes will make it more useful for beginners, because it will fit completely to my question.

Comment: Corrected, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This solution employs a lambda function and is more flexible -

```
list123 = ['01','02','03']
x=15                                     #limiting factor for str length
s123 = ' '.join(list123)                 #list elements become a str seperated by a space
s_space= lambda x:(x-len(s123))*' '      #store x-len(s123) spaces
s_left=s_space(x) +s123
s_right=s123 + s_space(x)
print(s_left)
```

Output : `'       01 02 03'`